# Mobile Menu "X" close goes above page on iPhones when scrolling

Tags: iphone, mobile

On https://sipwm.com/ for the mobile menu when you open it, the "x" to close it goes above the page and disappears on scroll for iPhones, resulting in being unable to close the menu. Before it was doing it on all browsers/phones so I changed it to position: fixed; but that didn't fix it on iPhones.

Any way to stick it just above the menu items on iPhone as well?

Before it was doing it on all browsers/phones so I changed it to position: fixed;

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the [tour], then read [Something in my web site or project doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/254428/354577)